# Ember.js integrate to Rails 3.2.8

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ember.js

I'm newbie to ember.js. I'm trying to integrate ember.js with Rails using [ember-rails](https://github.com/emberjs/ember-rails) gem. But when I start server and open my browser console I get following errors:

```
Uncaught Error: assertion failed: Ember Views require jQuery 1.7 :3000/assets/ember.js?body=1:43
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'extend' of undefined :3000/assets/ember-data.js?body=1:141
Uncaught ReferenceError: Blog is not defined :3000/assets/store.js?body=1:1
Uncaught ReferenceError: Blog is not defined :3000/assets/controllers/application_controller.js?body=1:1
Uncaught ReferenceError: Blog is not defined :3000/assets/views/application_view.js?body=1:1
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'template' of undefined :3000/assets/templates/application.js?body=1:1
Uncaught ReferenceError: Blog is not defined :3000/assets/routes/app_router.js?body=1:1
Uncaught ReferenceError: Blog is not defined :3000/assets/blog.js?body=1:10
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'create' of undefined ember.js:10183
Uncaught ReferenceError: Blog is not defined
```

How to solve it? Or how to integrate ember.js to rails by manually.

Thank you for advise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's the issue with ember-rails (https://github.com/emberjs/ember-rails/issues/88)

To force jquery to be 1.7, you can use the version 1.0.19 of the jquery-rails gem. So change your Gemfile to be:

```
gem "jquery-rails", "1.0.19"
```

And you'll be set.

As an alternative, you could follow the suggestion in the GH issue, and

```
var ENV = {'FORCE_JQUERY': true};
```

before the ember.js is loaded to override the requirement check for any version of jquery. (I have not tested this).

Comment: Thank you for reply. I really don't like oldest version of any gem. I think this gem is gone. Trying to integrate manually :(